# How to change the click handler of this image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<img src='img.png' onclick='document.write("Hi there!")' />
```

...and the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Change the click handler
    $('img').click(function() {

        alert("Hi there!");

    });

});
```

What I am expecting to happen is that the click handler for the image is replaced and that clicking it will produce an alert dialog. Instead, the page content changes, as dictated by the click handler in the tag.

How can I change the click handler at runtime?

**Note:** Here is an interactive demo you can play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykmaG/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the original `onclick`:

```
$('img').removeAttr('onclick').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Is the event bound to the element when the dom is loaded, if so then the `document.write` would still fire wouldn't they.

Comment: @Robert: What?   It will only fire when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the onclick attribute, instead stick with jQuery click().

To unbind an event, see [Unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind).

Does that help at all?